# How can I calculate the probability of a quantum system in superposition to be in the "up" state?

Tags: quantum-state

[image]

I've got this question to answer and from what I can tell, I need to take the square of the absolute value for the probability amplitude.

In this case I think the answer should be the square of $e^{i\phi} \cos(\theta)$

When I try to input this answer it returns "Phi is not a valid variable for this solution"

How do I go about tackling this question?

Comment: you seem to have forgotten to use the "absolute value" part that you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has most of the components of the answer: indeed you need to take the square of the absolute value for the probability amplitude.

You have to remember that $\cos \theta$ is a real number, and its absolute value is just $|\cos \theta|$, but $e^{i\phi}$ is a complex number (Euler's formula: $e^{i\phi}=\cos \phi + i \sin \phi$), so its absolute value is 1. The answer will be just $\cos^2 \theta$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was definitely over thinking the question :)

This field of maths is totally new to me, never used imaginary numbers. Just wanted to learn about nuclear power and they threw a quantum mechanics module at me lol

Thanks again